# Trying to convert if-else conditional to Assembly?

Tags: assembly, hla

How can I convert this to assembly language?
if((w == x)&&(x == y)&&(y == z)&&(z == w)) into HLA form with series of cmp and jmp command?

here my command so far:

```
program same;
#include("stdlib.hhf");
procedure theSame(w:int16; x:int16; y:int16; z:int16); @nodisplay; @noframe;

begin theSame;
*if((w == x)&&(x == y)&&(y == z)&&(z == w))*
mov(1, AL);
stdout.put("Same.", nl);
else
mov(0, AL);
stdout.put("Not the same", nl);
endif;
stdout.put("AL: ", (type int16 AL), nl);
end theSame;

begin sameOrnot;
stdout.put("Feed Me W: ");
stdin.get(w);
stdout.put("Feed Me X: ");
stdin.get(x);
stdout.put("Feed Me Y: ");
stdin.get(y);
stdout.put("Feed Me Z: ");
stdin.get(z);
theSame(w, x, y, z);
end sameOrnot;
```

Comment: Compilers can do this for you, creating an asm example that you can look at.  (https://godbolt.org/, and write a function that takes 4 `int` args so you can enable optimization without everything going away).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if((w == x)&&(x == y)&&(y == z)&&(z == w))
> ```

Unlike the bitwise **&** operator, **&&** guarantees left-to-right evaluation. So if `(w == x)` evaluates to *false*, no further evaluation is needed

```
  mov ax, w      ; (w == x)
  cmp ax, x
  jne IsFalse
  mov ax, x      ; &&(x == y)
  cmp ax, y
  jne IsFalse
  mov ax, y      ; &&(y == z)
  cmp ax, z
  jne IsFalse
  mov ax, z      ; &&(z == w)
  cmp ax, w
  jne IsFalse
IsTrue:
  ...
IsFalse:
  ...
```

The `&&(z == w)` part is redundant! Because of the guaranteed left-to-right evaluation, by the time we arrive at the 4th part, we already know that `w EQ x EQ y EQ z`. Associativity dictates that `w EQ z`.

We can also refrain from reloading the `AX` register because of the equality we got from each previous step.

```
  mov ax, w      ; (w == x)
  cmp ax, x
  jne IsFalse
                 ; AX already holds the value for x (same as w)
  cmp ax, y      ; &&(x == y)
  jne IsFalse
                 ; AX already holds the value for y (same as w)
  cmp ax, z      ; &&(y == z)
  jne IsFalse
IsTrue:
  ...
IsFalse:
  ...
```